# Not able to link dll using cmd.exe

Tags: python, dll

From last one week I got stuck in this error. I have a dll from third party which needs to be linked for my system to behave properly.

I have put the dll into the folder from where i am running the command prompt.

For e.g. My python script is in `C:/xyz` and also my dll is in the same folder. When i am running the python script (using iron python) from `cmd.exe` it says that the dll is not found.

I am able to run the same python script using iron python environment from visual studio and it is running fine.

What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "that needs to be linked" ? What is the component that uses the DLL, is it a Python plugin ? Then the problem is probably in some environment variables (%PATH%, or the one where Python looks for its extension). Another alternative is copying the DLL at the same place where Python has its own DLLs (C:\Pythonxxx\libs)

Comment: The component that uses the dll is another .net dll created by me. I have checked the path and the environment variables and there is no problem in that. I have already copied the dll into the "lib" folder of python but then also it is showing the same error.

Comment: Could you explain us better the relations between the different components ? There is cmd.exe, the python interpreter, your .net DLL and the other DLL, who is supposed to be linked to who and how ?

Comment: Ok sorry for the incomplete info. I have two types of dlls one which is created by me using .NET framework and other which is provided by third party. I have written a import.py where i have added the dlls created by me using : **clr.AddReferenceToFile('DLL created by me')** The dll provided by third party has been copied in the execution folder (i.e. the folder from where i am running the scripts). As it is a python script so i am using iron python interpreter(32 bit), the path has been added in the environment variables. So i open the cmd.exe and give command **ipy test.py**.

Comment: cmd.exe should try to link all the dlls and execute **test.py**. But the dll provided by third party is not getting linked. All the other dlls created by me is getting linked. I debugged that by using **Console.Writeline**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been resolved. The problem was that the third party dll should be present in the folder where iron python executable is present. 
For e.g if ipy.exe is present in the folder **C:\Program Files(x86)\Iron Python2.7** then the third party dll has to be present there.

The reason why it took me so long to figure this out because when i was using the previous version of the dll provided by the third party then it was not necessary to copy the dll in the path **C:\Program Files(x86)\Iron Python2.7**. But for the new version i have to do that. Strange it is!!